# How do I fix my function for printing time so it's not 8 hours slow?

Tags: c, time

This is a test for my C library that I created that prints the hours, minutes, and seconds of the day:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

time_t print_time(time_t t)
{
    if(!t) t = time(NULL);
    printf("%d:%.2d.%.2d\n", (t % (60*60*60))/(60*60), (t % (60*60))/60, t % 60);
    fflush(stdout);
    return t;
}

int main(void)
{
    print_time(0);
}
```

It was 10:56.42 where I was when I first ran this program, but the `print_time` function printed 2:56.42. How do I fix this?

I've tried subtracting `(t % (60*60*60))/(60*60)` from `12` and printing that, and it prints the correct time, but when the time changed to `11`, the time printed as `9`.

Comment: why not using the standard time functions? like `mktime` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre What would that be?

Comment: `60*60*60` that's 60 hours. You mean `24*60*60` maybe? I mean standard `mktime` function that sets a time structure with day & time

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Can you please put that in an answer?

Comment: Consider using `localtime` and `strftime` instead.

Comment: @melpomene That would be nice if I had those available, but I haven't implemented them yet. This is a test for my C library.

Comment: Which time zone are you living in?  The `time_t` value normally records the number of seconds since 'the Epoch' in UTC (GMT).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler UTC-4:00

Comment: The 8 hours is compounded from 12 hours due to using 60 hours per day instead of 24, and 4 hours due to your time zone.  When you correct the 60 to 24, you print the time in UTC.  You have to further adjust for your local time zone if you want to print local time — or accept that the corrected code prints the time in UTC and not local time.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'll accept that. I'll just rename the function to `print_utc_time`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`60*60*60` means 60 hours, not a day. You want something like:

```
printf("%d:%.2d.%.2d\n", (t % (24*60*60))/(60*60), (t % (60*60))/60, t % 60);
```

Here in France this program prints the proper time minus 2 hours (doesn't take into account daylight saving time (+1) added to UTC (+1 too)).

I suggest that you use standard library functions instead, like `localtime` or `gmtime`.

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm *tstruct = gmtime(&t);
```

now `tstruct` points on information, day, hour, you name it ...

```
struct tm {
   int tm_sec;         /* seconds,  range 0 to 59          */
   int tm_min;         /* minutes, range 0 to 59           */
   int tm_hour;        /* hours, range 0 to 23             */
   int tm_mday;        /* day of the month, range 1 to 31  */
   int tm_mon;         /* month, range 0 to 11             */
   int tm_year;        /* The number of years since 1900   */
   int tm_wday;        /* day of the week, range 0 to 6    */
   int tm_yday;        /* day in the year, range 0 to 365  */
   int tm_isdst;       /* daylight saving time             */   
};
```

Full example with your method & local & gm methods:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    printf("%d:%.2d.%.2d\n", (t % (24*60*60))/(60*60), (t % (60*60))/60, t % 60);
    struct tm *tstruct = gmtime(&t);
    printf("%d:%.2d.%.2d\n",tstruct->tm_hour,tstruct->tm_min,tstruct->tm_sec);
    tstruct = localtime(&t);
    printf("%d:%.2d.%.2d\n",tstruct->tm_hour,tstruct->tm_min,tstruct->tm_sec);
}
```

prints:

```
15:22.26
15:22.26
17:22.26
```

Seems that your code can now emulate hours from UTC time properly. Now more challenge with leap years and all...

If you can't use standard libs (except for `time()`) and you want *local* time, you also have to handle the timezone. You'll have to hardcode that in some custom setting (like operating system does).